# How to configure Bean class in root-context.xml file using STS in Spring?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-jdbc

I am new to Spring and going to develop a spring MVC Application.What is the best way to write root-context.xml for Bean class properties? 
For database Connection I want to use Spring jdbc(JdbcTemplate).Can you please suggest me the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to set up a DataSource and then create a JdbcTemplate bean that utilizes it. The [Spring JDBC Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) provides examples and really good explanations on how to accomplish this.

Here's a basic bean definition for a datasource. The properties specified will depend on the database that you are using.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Then you can create a jdbcTemplate bean that uses the dataSource or you can instantiate the jdbcTemplate within your code.

The [JdbcTemplate API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) mentions this:

> Can be used within a service implementation via direct instantiation with a DataSource reference, or get prepared in an application context and given to services as bean reference. Note: The DataSource should always be configured as a bean in the application context, in the first case given to the service directly, in the second case to the prepared template.

Comment: thanks that was helpful.But now I want to store dynamic values into database so how to declare all values from Bean class(UserBean.java its name of my bean class which has 'id','name') in root-context.xml file?

Comment: @Swikriti If you want to insert data into the database, you can do that a variety of ways. The JdbcTemplate has update(..) methods that allow you to execute SQL queries which return the number of rows that were affected. For instance, `jdbcTemplate.update("insert into users (name) values (?)", name);` This inserts a value for `name` into the `users` table. You'll have to check out the API for all available options. The API is very extensive and powerful.

Comment: Thanks John.Actually I want to know how to insert dynamic values in Spring root-context.xml file.for example i have my bean configure like this @code <property name="id" value="10"></property>  <property name="name" value="smith"></property>.So here i want to pass dynamic value which will store into database dynamically.